# Keras LSTM predicting only 1 category, in multi-category classification - how to fix?

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm, keras

I have a text dataset that has equal number of labels - `0,1,2,3,4`. I ran the `Keras binary classification` example `LSTM` (imdb example) on their website with my dataset and the compile line changed to

```
"model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', class_mode="categorical")"
```

But the model predicts only 1 category, that is, `20%` accuracy consistently.

Could you please help me fix it / change settings as required?

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  It may have to do with how you are encoding your labels.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to modify the with

```
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
```

where nb_classes corresponds to the number of categorical classes.